# SendMessageTimeout returns FALSE in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, process, handler

I am trying to find out if a process is not frozen by sending a message to its handler and see if it reaches it.
I cannot use `Process.Responding` because it looks like the monitored application needs to have a window. This has to work for processes that run without a window. I use this method but it always returns FALSE:

```
Const SMTO_BLOCK = &H1
Const SMTO_ABORTIFHUNG = &H2
Const WM_NULL = &H0

<DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError:=True, CharSet:=CharSet.Auto)>
Public Function SendMessageTimeout(hWnd As HandleRef, msg As Integer, wParam As IntPtr, lParam As IntPtr, flags As Integer, timeout As Integer, ByRef pdwResult As IntPtr) As IntPtr
End Function

Public Function ProcessIsResponding(ByVal proc As Process) As Boolean
    Dim handleRef As HandleRef = New HandleRef(proc, proc.Handle)
    Dim timeout As Integer = 10000
    Dim lpdwResult As IntPtr

    Dim lResult As IntPtr = SendMessageTimeout(handleRef, WM_NULL, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, SMTO_ABORTIFHUNG And SMTO_BLOCK, timeout, lpdwResult)

    Return lResult <> IntPtr.Zero
End Function
```

This works if I replace `proc.Handle` by `proc.MainWindowHandle` but I guess in this case a window handle is needed. What happens if there's no window? What other choice do I have?

Comment: If there is no window then you of course cannot use this approach.  And would be highly unreliable anyway, a process without any windows is normally in a "frozen" state.  Waiting for something that happens perhaps only once an hour.

Comment: I presume the target application is not written by you, but could be any application?

Comment: Yes, @StuartWhitehouse. The application runs on a remote server, through RemoteApp. As is the monitoring application. It looks like it doesn't detect when the monitored process is frozen, using `Process.Responding`